# How to reload a URL daily at a certain time using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I have a URL that is being invoked by a cron job, but I am not getting it to work.

I am planning to do the same using Javascript: how can I reload the page this way on particular hour of the day (8:00 PM)?

Comment: Execute JavaScript from command-line? Should we assume you don't mean Node but a regular browser? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i have one url that i wanna refresh daily once at 8pm....

Comment: cron job not working thtz y ...

Comment: @Hasif Please try to not use SMS languages as it will complicate the communication with others. You question is too broad and not clear. Do you have a website or a nodejs script ?

Comment: Oh, I thought everything was working fine but you decided to ask anyway xD -- It's totally unclear what "refresh" means in this context. Do you want to launch a remote script that's published as HTTP resource? Do you need to keep the connection open until it's done? Why does it need to be done in JavaScript? Do you know what Node is?

Comment: Calculate the time left between now and 8 p.m. Then use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to reload your web after the time expires

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, THanks for your advice. I'm working on it

Comment: Advice? I was asking questions...

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to reload a controller from the index page. I will write this script and place the URL in here – [*Hasif*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668332/how-to-reload-certain-url-daily-8pm-using-javascript#comment90299656_51668385)

Since the use of Javascript in your situation is restricted to the front-end, the user would need to keep the page open (*index* as you mentioned) the whole time. This means that:

- the URL call **will only be made if the user keeps the browser open** (if this task really needs to run everyday, you should not rely on the client side to make it happen);
- the cron-job you mentioned is the better alternative, but you have **no way to force the user's browser to open up at 8:00 PM everyday**;
- the user's local time will not be useful to trigger this event if the URL is supposed to be loaded for all users at the same time, so trigger it at a certain time in the **UTC timezone** (for example).

### Solution

1. Create a *cookie* that stores the date and time when the *index* page was last loaded by the user and each time the page loads, compare it to the current date and load the URL only once ([MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Example_3_Do_something_only_once)). You might want to set the cookie in the backend, but a simple example to store and load it in JS:

```js
var td =new Date(), date2store = `${td.getUTCFullYear()}-${td.getUTCMonth().toString().padStart(2,0)}-${td.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2,0)} ${td.getUTCHours().toString().padStart(2,0)}:${td.getUTCMinutes().toString().padStart(2,0)}`;
alert('Cookie to store: last_date=' + date2store + ' --> Is it after 8 PM UTC? ' + (new Date(date2store).getUTCHours() >= 19 ? 'YES!' : 'NO!' ));
```

2. If the user keeps the browser open until the next day use a simple script loaded into the page to check the current UTC hour and update:

```js
// place the code below in a setInterval(function() {...}, 1000*60*60);
// the if below should also the test the current cookie's datetime as the first condition
// 0 index hour exists (therefore compare with 19 instead of 20)
if(new Date().getUTCHours() >= 19) {
  alert('Past 8 PM');
  // save the current date and time in the cookie HERE
  
  // reload the index page
  // window.location.reload(true); // true for not using cache
  // OR redirect to a new location
  // window.location.href = 'https://...';
} else alert('Not 8 PM yet');
```

Answer (score -1):

The following JavaScript snippet will allow you to refresh at a given time:

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date();

if(now.getHours() > hours ||
   (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
    now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
    then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
then.setHours(hours);
then.setMinutes(minutes);
then.setSeconds(seconds);

var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
 }
```

Then you can add a script tag to call the refreshAt() function.

```
refreshAt(15,35,0); //Will refresh the page at 3:35pm
```

Comment: window.location.reload(true);   how can i give my url here? plz help me

Comment: you can pass it as another parameter in the function just had a param called url 

refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds, url) 

your question is a little bit unclear

Comment: @Hasif You make no sense, why would you give your url here? You can't reload a different url..

Comment: thanks for help. I wanted to reload a controller from index page. in index page ill write this script and ill put calling url here